# Prevent duplication of Class Entries into database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to prevent the duplication of data on my database. I have two option one is for class name and the other one is class code, but every time I select same data it always insert in to the database, I want is to prevent the duplication

[This is the code when button is submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RltTU.png)

What I want is to prevent duplication of data for example student or enter and select class 1 and class code: 123, if the students enter this class 1 and class code 123 again, the student cannot enter the class because he/she was already in the class.

```
if($selectTheclassroomcheck > 0){ 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectTheclassroom);
    $insertIntoTheClassParticipant = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO teacher_class_student (teacher_class_id,student_id, teacher_id, class_id) VALUES ('".$row['teacher_class_id']."','".$_SESSION['id']."','".$row['teacher_id']."','0')");
    if($insertIntoTheClassParticipant){
        echo json_encode(1); //You are successfully enter to class
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode(2);//Incorrect class
    }
}
else{
    echo json_encode(2);

}

?>
```

Comment: Please post actual code and not an image of it. You also need to tell us what isn't working the way you'd like it to, if there are any errors; given you're checking for them and I doubt you are.

Answer (score 1):

[create a unique index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html) on `student_id, class, class_code` (which ever columns these correspond to). When the second insert of this combination occurs a duplicate key error will occur. Catch this in your application an display an approprate error message.

Use [INSERT ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) to avoid your application doing this.

Also read: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)